# Pintar celda datatable

Tags: datatable

Necesito ayuda, en el sistema de información en el que estoy trabajando para listar la información de los cumpleaños de los trabajadores uso Datatable pero necesito pintar las celdas (Los días que que faltan para cumplir años) de el color respectivo osea:

1. Si es menor o igual a 2 días (Rojo)
2. Si es menor o igual a 10 días (Naranja)
3. Si es menor o igual a 20 días (Azul)
4. El resto osea mayor a 20 días de color (Verde)

Pero no he podido ya que soy nuevo en esto de la programación me seria de gran ayuda que alguien me respondiera. Gracias!!

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
listarCumpleanos();
});

function listarCumpleanos(){
var tablaModalCumpleaños=$("#tablaModalCumpleaños").DataTable({

 // Verde: #90EE90
  // Rojo: #E60026
  // Naranja: #E65F00
  // Azul: #ADD8E6

  rowCallback:function(row,data){
   if(data[5] <= 2){
    $($(row).find("td")[5]).css("background-color","#E60026");
   }
   else if(data[5] <= 10){
    $($(row).find("td")[5]).css("background-color","#E65F00");
   }
   else if(data[5] <= 20){
    $($(row).find("td")[5]).css("background-color","#ADD8E6");
   }
   else{
    $($(row).find("td")[5]).css("background-color","#E60026");
   }
  },


  destroy: true,
  order: [[ 5, "asc" ]],
  columnDefs: [{"className": "dt-center", "targets": "_all"}],
 });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"></script>


<table id='tablaModalCumpleaños' class='tablaModalCumpleaños display' cellspacing='0'>
     <thead>
      <tr>
       <th>IDENTIFICACIÓN</th>
       <th>NOMBRES</th>
       <th>APELLIDOS</th>
       <th style="width: 10%;">FECHA INICIO</th>
       <th style="width: 10%;">FECHA FIN</th>
       <th>DÍAS</th>
       <th>COLEGIO</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td>1107851551</td>
       <td>ESTEBAN</td>
       <td>PAZ</td>
       <td>2018-04-01</td>
       <td>2018-04-05</td>
       <td>2</td>
       <td>COLEGIO LA ASUNCION</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
       <td>114555551</td>
       <td>DANIEL</td>
       <td>PAZ</td>
       <td>2019-04-01</td>
       <td>2020-04-05</td>
       <td>10</td>
       <td>COLEGIO SIH SEDE INVICALI</td>
      </tr>


      <tr>
       <td>114555551</td>
       <td>ALEJANDRO</td>
       <td>RAMIREZ</td>
       <td>2016-04-01</td>
       <td>2020-04-05</td>
       <td>20</td>
       <td>COLEGIO SIH SEDE ALFONSO LOPEZ</td>
      </tr>


      <tr>
       <td>114555551</td>
       <td>CARLOS</td>
       <td>GOMEZ</td>
       <td>2017-04-01</td>
       <td>2020-04-05</td>
       <td>40</td>
       <td>COLEGIO SIH SEDE ALFONSO LOPEZ</td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
     <tfoot>
      <tr>
       <th>IDENTIFICACIÓN</th>
       <th>NOMBRES</th>
       <th>APELLIDOS</th>
       <th style="width: 10%;">FECHA INICIO</th>
       <th style="width: 10%;">FECHA FIN</th>
       <th>DÍAS</th>
       <th>COLEGIO</th>
      </tr>
     </tfoot>
    </table>
```

Comment: Bienvenido, te invito a darte un paseo por el [tour] y a echarle un vistazo a [ask] y a [mcve]. ¿Podrías poner el código que tienes?

Comment: Ya agregue, el código la verdad no soy experto en datatables y soy nuevo programando encontre ese código en este mismo foro y lo que hice fue  intentar ver si acoplandolo al mío funcionaba pero solo me arroja el color rojo.

Comment: ¿Puedes poner tu html?

Comment: Oye perdón es que soy nuevo en este foro como hago para agregarlo?

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pega el código ;)

Comment: Ya me guié con un ejemplo xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La sitanxsis para agregar colores está correcta, no entiendo muy bien pero en ocaciones no lo hace. Intenta con retorna una función.

```
$($(row).find("td")[5]).css("background-color", function( index ) {
  return "E60026";
});
```

Sí aun sigue sin funcionar, define los colores en una hoja de estilo y agrega su respectiva clase.

```
// Verde: #90EE90
        // Rojo: #E60026
        // Naranja: #E65F00
        // Azul: #ADD8E6
$($(row).find("td")[5]).addClass("Verde");
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu tiempo y por ayudarme, al final decidí hacerlo mediante php y enviarle el texto ya coloreado a el datatable.